# Get Worksheet Names of Opened Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code where the user is promted to select a workbook, I want to ensure that the user is selecting a specific file, and to do this I want to verify upon opening the workbook that the Sheet names are matching what I am expecting them to be:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
        Dim Ret1
        Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

        Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
        , "Please a file to load from")
        If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)

    If wb2.Sheet1.Name = "Sum" And wb2.Sheet2.Name = "Names" And wb2.Sheet3.Name = "Things" Then
    MsgBox "Fine"
'Code Here
    Else
    MsgBox "Issue"
'Code Here
    End If

        wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Set wb2 = Nothing
        Set wb1 = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Unfortunately when I run the above code I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method error." on the line `If wb2.Sheet1.Name = "Sum" And wb2.Sheet2.Name = "Names" And wb2.Sheet3.Name = "Things"`

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, sticking closer to his original script, change `wb1.sheet#.Name` to `wb1.sheets(#).Name` like this:

```
    If wb2.Sheets(1).Name = "Sum" And wb2.Sheets(2).Name = "Names" And wb2.Sheets(3).Name = "Things" Then
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function to check whether sheet exist or not:

```
Function IsSheetExist(wb As Workbook, shName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(shName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsSheetExist = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

and use it like this:

```
If IsSheetExist(wb2, "Sum") And IsSheetExist(wb2, "Names") And IsSheetExist(wb2, "Things") Then
    MsgBox "Fine"
    'Code Here
Else
    MsgBox "Issue"
    'Code Here
End If
```

---

if you want to check whether thouse sheets exist in workbook *in specific order*, you can use this approach:

```
Function IsContainsSheetsInOrder(wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    IsContainsSheetsInOrder = False

    If wb.Sheets.Count < 3 Then Exit Function
    If wb.Sheets(1).Name <> "Sum" Then Exit Function
    If wb.Sheets(2).Name <> "Names" Then Exit Function
    If wb.Sheets(3).Name <> "Things" Then Exit Function

    IsContainsSheetsInOrder = True
End Function
```

and then:

```
If IsContainsSheetsInOrder(wb2) Then
    MsgBox "Fine"
    'Code Here
Else
    MsgBox "Issue"
    'Code Here
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems like a bit too much code. I was looking for a fix to the line which gave me the error. The answer @TheMadTechnician did just that.

Comment: As I see your main intension to check whether user opens correct workbook, but note, that in his answer if user opens workbook with, say two or one worksheet, your code would fail with runtime error..

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, I covered it by adding `On Error GoTo Err` before the `If` statement and adding `Err:` after the `Else` statement. But a keen observation, Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent point @simoco ...@CaptainABC, you're going to want to add his `If wb1.sheets.count < 3 then` bit in there just to be safe.

Comment: `Function IsSheetExist()` + 1 Correct way of doing it :)